# How to change an object when an option is selected in a dropdown in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

Consider this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/martijngr/ADukg/3103/)

As you can see it's just a simple form with a dropdown and a binding. I mention two views in the fiddle: detail and edit. The detail view displays everything in plain text and the edit view is a form where changes can take place.

What I try to achieve is, is when the dropdown changes the value, I want to update the `User.title` object on the fly. How can I achieve this?

Edit:
In the dropdown I need to know which id is selected when the form is posted. I also need to know the id to set the selected value of the dropdown.

Comment: Is User.title.description going to be the name of the selected title?

Comment: Your fiddle is quite confusing because you sometime use "title.description", sometime "title.name". Then the model is "User.title.id" when you apparently want to change "User.title". Maybe consider cleaning up your fiddle to show what you actually want to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With ng-model you bind the view into the model.

But in the ng-options directive, the part before 'as' binds more 'model' ontop of the one provided in ng-model. If you omit title.id then the whole  object will become the 'extra model' `{id: .., name: ..}`

http://jsfiddle.net/rLjC5/1/

PS: That's why you can't use ng-options without ng-model.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the fiddle. This is almost what I want, but I am using this in a form. And when I submit it this way, I don't know the Id of the selected title. That's why I use the id in the ng-options. Another reason is that my selected value is now gone.

Answer (score 1):

You obviously want a default value selected in the drop down. You haveto initialize your `User.title` object based on a value of the titles array.

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/3105/) out.

Comment: Thanks. And how do I know the id of the selected value when this form is submitted? In your fiddle the values of the id are 1, 2, 3. What if the id's are 12, 13, 14?

Comment: The User.title.id knows the selected ID. In my Fiddle, replace the first mustache template with `{{ User.title | json }}`, you will see that the all `User.title` object is updating. Edit: see this updated fidle : http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/3106/

Comment: Thanks. I didn't look close enough what you were doing, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it is binding the select's model to User.title.

```
<select data-ng-model="User.title" data-ng-options="title.name for title in titles"
```

Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vR274/1/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this is also what jamiltz suggested. The problem I have with this approach is that 1) I don't know which id is selected and 2) as you can see, the selected value has gone.